# Gmail-API Problems with modifying the message (Insufficient Permission) c#

Tags: gmail-api

I have a situation that I can not allow an email (Gmail) to enable its permissions for the Gmail API, set the message to READ(C#),interesting is that when I generate the token in google's website and asks me to confirm the enable feature, it only gives me the option to enable reading not the modification, this case is a business domain email, what should I do to enable the permission?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?  (suggestion:  cut and paste the error message into your original question)

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask